# What is the default fstab file?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I was editing my fstab and somehow [spooky music] deleted it. As you can imagine this has caused some problems and I have searched online for the shape of the default file to no avail.

Can someone with a working setup just run `cat /etc/fstab` and post the results please? I understand I will have to change the UUIDs.

I'm on Raspberry Pi 3, running Raspbian following the standard tutorial.

Maybe someone could also include the pi-2 setup for completeness..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Raspberry Pi 3.

> cat /etc/fstab

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0 0
PARTUUID=232c31bf-01  /boot           vfat    defaults 0       2
PARTUUID=232c31bf-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime 0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Comment: Note that the PARTUUID needs to be adjusted, unless the OP used exactly the same image as you did.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Exactly.  The OP acknowledged this when he said: "I understand I will have to change the UUIDs," in his post.

Comment: @Sanders If I'm not mistaken, he added this line to his post *after* my comment. You kinda make it sound like I didn't read the question well enough.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I did not know he added that line after the fact.  I just self-educated myself how to check what was edited.  Please accept my apology for sounding disrespectable - that was not my intent as I was completely agreeing with you.

Comment: No, I did not add that line after your post Dmitry. I knew I had to change the IDs. Sanders was right, I acknowledged it. And you didn't read the question well enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standard" - generally **PARTUUID** depends on the specific image installed. (It can also be changed - which I do routinely.)

I use the following code to verify images, as it often gets confused restoring from backups.

```
#! /bin/sh
# 2021-02-10

#   Check consistency of Disk identifier in cmdline.txt /etc/fstab

# Determine Disk identifier
DISKID=$(sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0 | awk '/Disk identifier/ {print $3};' | sed 's/0x//')

# Use sed to delete all BEFORE PARTUUID= and all AFTER -0  in /boot/cmdline.txt
ROOTPART=$(sed -e 's/^.*PARTUUID=//' -e 's/-0.*$'// /boot/cmdline.txt)
echo "Disk ID\t\t"$DISKID
echo "root PARTUUID\t"$ROOTPART

# find first PARTUUID ext4 in /etc/fstab
EXISTFSTABPART=$(awk '/PARTUUID.*ext4/ {print $1; exit};' /etc/fstab | sed -e 's/^.*PARTUUID=//' -e 's/-0.*$'//)

echo "Existing fstab\t"$EXISTFSTABPART

if [ $DISKID = $EXISTFSTABPART ]; then
    echo "Looks OK!"
# else
fi
```